# JSF Clear form data when checkbox is unselected

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

For an assignment I have a form that takes 4 ints (representing an IP Address). When switching between 2 pages, the IP address and the subnet information must be retained only when a checkbox is selected. So far all attempts I have made either reset everything when the page loads(and as a result, whenever I submit the form) or doesn't clear at all. Any suggestions on how to approach this?

**Backing Bean**

```
@ManagedBean(name="controllerBean" )
@SessionScoped
public class CalculatorController implements Serializable{
CalculatorModel model;

public CalculatorModel getModel(){
    return model;
}

public CalculatorController(){
    super();
       model =  new CalculatorModel();     
}
}
```

**Part of the form**

```
<h:form id="calculator">

                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th><h5>IP Address</h5></th>
                        <th><h5>Prefix Length</h5></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                                <h:inputText
                                    id="firstOctet"
                                    label="First Octet"
                                    required="true"
                                    size="1"
                                    maxlength="3"
                                    requiredMessage="Enter a valid "
                                    value="#{controllerBean.model.firstOctet}">
                                    </h:inputText>
```

The form contains 3 more inputTexts(for the other octets), a button and a few tables to show the results of the calculations.

Comment: You should post your code so we an analyse it.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late for your assignment, hope you figured it out. Here's how I'd do it:

```
     <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th><h5>IP Address</h5></th>
                    <th><h5>Prefix Length</h5></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                            <h:inputText
                                id="firstOctet"
                                label="First Octet"
                                required="true"
                                size="1"
                                maxlength="3"
                                requiredMessage="Enter a valid "
                                value="#{controllerBean.model.firstOctet}">
                                </h:inputText>  
                            <!-- more inputs here-->
                 <h:selectOneBoolean value="#{controllerBean.saveValues}" />
                 <h:outputLabel value="Save Values?" />
                 <h:commandButton action="#{controllerBean.submit}" value="Go to other page"/>
```

And controller bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="controllerBean" )
@SessionScoped
public class CalculatorController implements Serializable{
  CalculatorModel model;
  boolean saveValues;

  /*  ...Getters and setters for CalculatorModel and saveValues... */

  public CalculatorController(){
    super();
    model =  new CalculatorModel();     
  }

  public String submit() {
    if (!saveValues) {
      model.setFirstOctet(0);
      // ... etc
      model.setPrefixLength(0);
    }
    return "next-view-id";
  }
}
```